# При добавлении строки меняется формула

Tags: функции, excel, excel-формулы

На листе "Сводка" есть формула `=ЕСЛИ('Табель'!$B$2="";'Табель'!$A$2+C1;"")`. При вставке строки между 1-ой и 2-ой строкой на листе «Табель» формула на листе "Сводка" меняется на `=ЕСЛИ('Табель'!$B$3="";'Табель'!$A$3+C1;"")`.
Как записать формулу, чтобы она не менялась при добавлении новой строки на листе «Табель»?
Замена `C1` на `$C$1` ничего не даёт.

Comment: если надо выбирать именно 2 строку и 2 столбец, можно вместо `'Табель'!$B$2` использовать `ДВССЫЛ(АДРЕС(2;2;1;1;"табель");1)`

Comment: @Tunker ввод ДВССЫЛ(АДРЕС(2;2;1;1;"табель");1) вместо 'Табель'!$B$2 выдаёт "#ОШИБКА!".

Comment: @Tunker, благодарю за наводку.
Изменил формулу на =ЕСЛИ(ДВССЫЛ("'Табель'!B2")="";ДВССЫЛ("'Табель'!A2")+C1;"") и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ЕСЛИ(ДВССЫЛ("Табель!B2")="";ДВССЫЛ("Табель!A2")+C1;"")
```

Но это для ознакомления, использовать не рекомендую. ДВССЫЛ медленная и вызывает пересчет формулы при любом действии на листе.

`ИНДЕКС` быстрая, нелетучая и не имеет недостатков , которыми богата `ДВССЫЛ`:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИНДЕКС(Табель!$B:$B;2)="";ИНДЕКС(Табель!$A:$A;2)+C1;"")
```

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку. ИНДЕКС, действительно, будет пошустрее.